# Mutually Exclusive Checkboxes - C#, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, checkbox

I am writing a program which will have two possibilities: Set Time & Date Manually, or use Computer/System Time & Date.

So now I need to make two Checkboxes which are Mutually Exclusive. When one will be chosen, another must be Unchecked. How to do it this in MVVM?

```
<CheckBox Name="UseSystemTime" Margin="7"  Content="Use System Time and Date settings (Time, Date, DST, Timezone)" IsChecked="{Binding UseSystemTime}"/>
<CheckBox Name="ManualTime" Margin="7"  Content="Set settings Manually" IsChecked="{Binding SetSettingsManually}"/>
```

Is there a way to do this in XAML?

[WPF coding mutually exclusive Checkboxes with Data Binding](http://www.helplessautomation.com/2011/01/wpf-coding-mutually-exclusive-check-boxes-with-data-binding/)

Thanks!

Comment: If any question needed please ask

Comment: Why wouldn't you use radio buttons for this? They are the traditional way of displaying mutually exclusive options and it would probably be easier to set up.

Comment: Thanks for Idea. Also thought on this. But the form of checkbox is more beautiful (more user friendly) - I think so :) I would rather do with checkboxes, or it is possible to change the shape of radiobutton to checkbox form? :) With checkmark and everythink? :)

Comment: You should always ask your users what they like, never consider your opinion as the best one when making any kind of software. Using radio buttons (with default look) is standard behavior when you need mutually exclusive behavior. Changing default look to some other standard control can confuse your users. The fact that you can do something doesn't mean you should always do it.

Comment: After all these comments, if you still want to use the same way that you did, than you need converter for your IsChecked properties. Probably a converter with MultiBinding

Comment: Technically, you need only one `CheckBox`. When checked, system time is used, otherwise, user has to set it manually. UI should be simple, understandable and straight forward, not necessarily beautiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case of having only 2 `checkboxes` i would introduce only one bool-property in my viewmodel for the ManualTime like.

```
public bool IsManualTimeUsed
{
   // get;set with property-changed 
}
```

Then in the UI you have two opportunities:

**Opportunity 1:**

```
 <CheckBox Name="UseSystemTime" Margin="7" Content="Use System Time and Date settings (Time, Date, DST, Timezone)" 
           IsChecked="{Binding IsManualTimeUsed, Converter{converterNamespace:InverseBoolConverter}}"/>
 <CheckBox Name="ManualTime" Margin="7" Content="Set settings Manually" 
           IsChecked="{Binding IsManualTimeUsed}"/>
```

where the InverseBoolConverter can look like:

```
public class InverseBoolConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    private static InverseBoolConverter converter;

    public InverseBoolConverter()
    {

    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
            return !((bool) value);
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return converter ?? (converter = new InverseBoolConverter());
    }
}
```

**Opportunity 2**

```
<CheckBox Name="UseSystemTime" Margin="7" Content="Use System Time and Date settings (Time, Date, DST, Timezone)" 
          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=ManualTime, Path=IsChecked, Converter={converterNamespace:InverseBoolConverter}}"/>
<CheckBox Name="ManualTime" Margin="7" Content="Set settings Manually" 
          IsChecked="{Binding IsManualTimeUsed}"/>
```

with the same converter as in opportunity 1

Comment: I trying "Opportunity 2" and I get error: "InverseBoolConverter is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.". Why I get that? I implemented both - XAML code and C# in view model.

Comment: I've recommend to place converters in a seperate folder called Converter. Than in the Window-Declaration in your XAML you have to include it with `xmlns:converter=PATHTOCONVERTER` than you can use it

Answer (score 0):

You can implement BootToCheckBoxConvertor  from IValueConverter interface and pass ConvertorParameter to check uncheck the checkboxes.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> But the form of checkbox is more beautiful (more user friendly) - I think so :) I would rather do with checkboxes, or it is possible to change the shape of radiobutton to checkbox form? :) With checkmark and everythink? :)

You can create a style for `RadioButton` that makes it look like a `CheckBox`:

```
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                                <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And use it like this:

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxRadioButtonStyle}" />
```

(I just used the default `CheckBox` style and changed the target type)

However, I strongly suggest that you use a normal radio button, because users are familiar with it. Mutually exclusive checkboxes will probably feel weird to the users.